# Download manager for joomla

Tags: joomla

hi there everyone i have a question on joomla, i have made a site using joomla and in my site on the left navigation part there is my items and packages and on that left nav under that i want a download manager where the visitors can download all the case studys,wallpapers,questionnaires,showreels etc.. which iam having on my site and also on the left nav part i want a ip based messages like if any user from france enters the site it should say "welcome to our friends of France" so i want to know is there any specific component for doing all this or just need the inputs from u all on how to do all this through joomla and what will b the logic and it will b helpful u guys have any ideas about doing this in a different way.

thanks a lot in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go through
this link you will found many joomla download manage components.

[manager]
 http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/directory-a-documentation/downloads

Comment: thanks a lot that helped a lot and another thing if u have any idea about displaying the message based on ip that will be a lot of help.

Answer (score 0):

Use this - http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/directory-a-documentation/downloads/82
Its best for your purpose.

Thanks
Shyam

Comment: thanks a lot for ur response and one more thing if u have used any of these components which will u suggest to me or u think is the best one

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the extension ccDownloads:
http://www.chillcreations.com/joomla-extensions/ccdownloads-joomla-download-extension